# Tail Probability limits

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We see the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nP(X\ge n)$ show up a lot in probability theory, when dealing with expectations. I was wondering how to show that the terms tend to 0? ($nP(X\ge n)\rightarrow 0$)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $X$ is the random variable here, then $nP( X \geq n) \leq nE[ \frac{X}{n} 1_{ X \geq n}] = E[ X 1_{X \geq n}]$ . If you take limit as $n$ goes to $\infty$ by dominated convergence theorem you can put the limit inside of the right hand side and it'll go to zero. This is somewhat well known.

Other than this if the sum is finite then limit must be zero from elementary calculus properties.

Comment: can you prove this without measure theoretic results?